# Using javascript Not able to disable textbox.It Immediatly enable after disabled. Can anyone give me solution?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have One simple registration Form which is developed in C#.Net. This form also contain one Grid view which display data from database.In this,I want to disable Insert button when i select particular raw data. and i had develop this code in jquery. I used below code.

```
function DoStuff(lnk) {
        debugger;
        var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
        var cell, row, rowIndex, cellIndex;
        cell = lnk.parentNode;
        row = cell.parentNode;
        rowIndex = row.rowIndex;
        cellIndex = cell.cellIndex;

        var rowId = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[0].textContent;
        var rowname = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[1].textContent;
        var rowcontact = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[2].innerHTML;
        var rowaddress = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[3].innerHTML;
        var rowemail = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[4].innerHTML;
        var Id = document.getElementById('txt_Id');
        var name = document.getElementById('txt_Name');
        var contact = document.getElementById('txt_PhoneNumber');
        var address = document.getElementById('txt_Address');
        var email = document.getElementById('txt_EmailId');


        Id.value = rowId;
        name.value = rowname;
        contact.value = rowcontact;
        address.value = rowaddress;
        email.value = rowemail;
       document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = true;
                };
```

But when i run that page it becomes disable and immediately enable automatically.....:( 
Can anyone give me solution ???

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this function after form is completely loaded.
Use below code to make it that happen if you are using jQuery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    DoStuff(lnk);
});
```